# Scapy AsyncSniffer fails if stop() is called right after start()

Tags: asynchronous, scapy, packet-sniffers, sniffing, sniffer

Look at the following example

```
a = AsyncSniffer()
a.start()
a.stop()
```

a.stop() will throw an exception. Is there a way to fix this without adding a time.sleep() between the start() and stop()?

- this ofcourse is a contrived example but the code in our project has the same problem if I create a test stub in between the start() and the stop()

**Update:**
tracebak from pycharm run:

```
FAILED                         [100%]
test_async_sniffer.py:3 (test_async_sniffer)
self = <scapy.sendrecv.AsyncSniffer object at 0x7f1d57a7f1f0>, join = True

    def stop(self, join=True):
        """Stops AsyncSniffer if not in async mode"""
        if self.running:
            try:
>               self.stop_cb()
E               AttributeError: 'AsyncSniffer' object has no attribute 'stop_cb'

venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py:1017: AttributeError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    def test_async_sniffer():
        a = AsyncSniffer()
        a.start()
>       a.stop()

test_async_sniffer.py:7: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <scapy.sendrecv.AsyncSniffer object at 0x7f1d57a7f1f0>, join = True

    def stop(self, join=True):
        """Stops AsyncSniffer if not in async mode"""
        if self.running:
            try:
                self.stop_cb()
            except AttributeError:
>               raise Scapy_Exception(
                    "Unsupported (offline or unsupported socket)"
                )
E               scapy.error.Scapy_Exception: Unsupported (offline or unsupported socket)

venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py:1019: Scapy_Exception
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible answer although not pretty:

```
    a = AsyncSniffer()
    a.start()
    if not hasattr(a, 'stop_cb'):
        time.sleep(0.06)
    a.stop()
```

seems the `start()` creates the attribute `stop_cb`, and if `stop()` is called right after `start()` the `stop_cb` has not been created yet, so I add an hasattr with a sleep (testing shows 0.06 secs is sufficient time but I guess it's very arbitrary)

Comment: Reading the answer I reliase I just added a time.sleep with an if block... Exactly what I asked not to do in the question...